# Reentrant Read/Write locks in eclipse have two lock/unlock methods

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, reentrantlock

I noticed that while calling lock/unlock on a ReentrantReadWrite lock, I am prompt with two lock and unlock methods. [image: locks]

For example, in the WriteLock I have a Lock() with -75% and another Lock() with no %. Both of these have the same documentations. I tried to find a reason online, but could not find any explanation. Is it just a bug in eclipse?

Comment: this is just eclipse's prediction I believe, it ranks methods by relevancy of use.

Comment: the odd thing is that the ReadLock is 25%, and the unlock are 50% both. So I am trying to understand if this is a prediction of write vs. read (which sounds odd, because you perform more reads), or is it something else

Comment: this is just eclipse trying to predict what you're going to use for your convenience, much like microsoft's intellisense.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to double-check those method names.

[`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) doesn't have a `Lock` method.  It has [`public ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock readLock()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html#readLock%28%29) and [`public ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock writeLock()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html#writeLock%28%29).  Those both implement the [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) interface and have lock(), lockInterruptibly(), unlock(), and trylock() methods.

The WriteLock has a few extra methods since write locks are generally exclusive.

Comment: Powelord, you are right I should have included this in my question, but even for WriteLock the two writelocks calls differ by this %. I guess as rpg711 said it is a prediction.